# Verb for creating an icon

Tags: word-usage, tenses, dictionaries

I am having some difficulty wording a title for a paper of mine. I am going for something like, "Automatic text iconification". Which means an automatic method of giving text a symbolic representation.

However, online dictionaries are not helping:

- **iconification** is found on [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iconification) but not webster or reference.com
- **iconify** is not found on webster and the case seems weird if I used "iconifing"

What word/tense do I use to make this correct?

Comment: The present participle should be spelled "iconifying".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Oxford English Dictionary has an entry for *iconize*. Its earliest, and obsolete, meaning is ‘to form into an image; to figure, to represent’, and is illustrated by a citation from 1678. From 1986 it is found in the computing industry to mean ‘to transform (a window) into an icon; to represent (a function or program) with an icon.’ An alternative is *iconify*.

Comment: So would iconization be correct?

Comment: @AustinHenley http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/iconisation

Comment: More interestingly, does this mean automatic iconification of text, or iconification of automatic text? The structure supports either interpretation. The -ific- (rather than -iz-) internal, btw, is a fossilized remnant of the Latin verb _facere_ 'make, do', which indicates (normally conscious) volition involved in the change.